anchor_lang::AccountDeserialize
How to implement correctly try_deserialize and try_deserialize_unchecked for this Example struct? I've been trying, but failing miserably.
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ExampleProgram;

declare_id!("ExampleProgramid00000000000000000001");

impl anchor_lang::Id for ExampleProgram{
    fn id() -> Pubkey {
        ID
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, PartialEq, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Example {
    pub x: Pubkey,
    pub y: u64,
    pub z: u8,    
}
impl anchor_lang::AccountDeserialize for Example {
    fn try_deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        //How do i do here?
    }

    fn try_deserialize_unchecked(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        //How do i do here?
    }
}

impl anchor_lang::AccountSerialize for Example {}

impl anchor_lang::Owner for Example {
    fn owner() -> Pubkey {
        ID
    }
}


If you're doing it by hand, your implementation of AnchorDeserialize is entirely up to you! The idea is that, given a bunch of bytes, you try to create an instance of Example out of it.
So in your example, you have a Pubkey (32 bytes), u64 (8 bytes), and u8 (1 bytes). If you assume that it's encoded in exactly that order, then you can deserialize it in the following way:
    fn try_deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        let (x_bytes, rest) = buf.split_at(32);
        *buf = rest;
        let x = Pubkey::try_from(pubkey_bytes).unwrap();
        let (y_bytes, rest) = buf.split_at(std::mem::size_of::<u64>());
        *buf = rest;
        let y = u64::from_le_bytes(y_bytes.try_into().unwrap())
        let (z_bytes, rest) = buf.split_at(std::mem::size_of::<u8>());
        *buf = rest;
        let z = u8::from_le_bytes(z_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
        Ok(Example { x, y, z })
    }

Note that due to the unwrap()s, this will panic on improper input, so should not be used for a production program.
For the most part, you don't need to do this by hand, and using the AnchorDeserialize macro will produce something usable. You can also use a tool like cargo expand to see what the macro generates.
